# How to test for FileNotFound exception when file is available in pytest

Tags: python, exception, triggers, pytest, raise

My Python module is invoking another binary. Since the binary might be missing on the target system, I'm checking for this in the code, which looks similar to this:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output([binary, options]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
except FileNotFoundError:
    raise Error('binary not found')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    raise Error('some other error')
```

I'm using pytest to test my code and want to have as much code coverage as possible. Now I'm wondering how to best test for the `FileNotFound` error. Since the binary is available on my system and is required for all of the other tests, its not really an option to not install this binary.

Comment: mock `subprocess.check_output` to raise `FileNotFoundError` when called with binary in command parameters.

Comment: Either modify `subprocess.check_output` in that test, or modify `binary` in the test. If `binary` path is read from some external configuration, that may be the simpler approach. Then again, modifying `check_output` will let you make it return e.g. something which will fail in `decode` (something that your code does not expect)

Comment: Mock `check_output` should be a more pythonical way. Suppose if you cannot modify `binary` in the test